# Applications of Govorov-Lazard Theorem?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

The Govorov-Lazard Theorem states that a (right) module over an unital ring is flat iff it is a direct limit of finitely generated free (right) modules.

I wonder if this theorem has interesting applications ?

Comment: Continued at MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/127769/